# Is it possible to set the min-height of a div with a variable based on height of floated ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul floated left that is a vertical tab navigation for a container div next to it. The container div is filled with the same number of divs as the ul has li's. Basically, I need the min-height of the container div (.selector-content) to be calculated from the height of the ul (.selector). As there are several instances of this arrangement on my page, it would be nice if each div would resize based on it's corresponding ul. The ul and div are both in a panel of an accordion. The functionality comes from the tabs in jQuery. If there is a jQuery function that can do this, that would be excellent. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<div class="accordion">
 <p class="ac-head current">Panel 1</p>
  <div class="panel">
   <ul class="selector">
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
    <li>Tab 4</li>
    <li>Tab 5</li>
   </ul>
  <div class="selector-content">
   <div class="content">Tab 1 Content</div>
   <div class="content">Tab 2 Content</div>
   <div class="content">Tab 3 Content</div>
   <div class="content">Tab 4 Content</div>
   <div class="content">Tab 5 Content</div>
  </div> <!-- Close selector-content -->
 </div> <!-- Close panel -->
</div> <!-- Close accordion -->    
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just simply: ?

```
$("div.panel").css({ "min-height": $("ul.selector").height() });
```

Comment: Just did, and it doesn't seem to work. I may be going about this backwards, but I would prefer the selector-content div to resize. When I switched "div.panel" to "div.selector-content", it resizes to the content, not the height of the ul for some reason.

Comment: would the ul being float:left have anything to do with it? perhaps I could count the number of li's and return that height?

Comment: For now I have given up and just set the min-height of the selector-content div to greater than the largest navigation ul. The thinking behind trying to do it dynamically would be if li's were added by the end users after I have put the page in place, as it may not be maintained by me for all eternity.